# How to get users's location and Venue in a bot telegram by telepot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

I'm creating a bot with Python telepot for the bus itineraries. I don't understand how to manage commands, can anyone explain to me how I can get the position (street name) of a user who uses my bot?

```
import json
import time
from pprint import pprint
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import telepot.namedtuple
bot = telepot.Bot("token")
lista = ["New York","Los Angeles","Miami","Toronto","Berlin","Rome"]
seq = iter(lista)
keyboard = {"keyboard": [[{"text": i} for i in pair] for pair in zip(seq)]}
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)

    if content_type == "text":
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, msg["text"], reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.editMessageLiveLocation(latitude, longitude) #i've tried here but nothing




MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Show us the code you are running, along with printed output of a response.

Comment: I've done it! Ok?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us printed output for the `msg` response that came back.

Within the `if`, the 1st line makes sense, it conforms to
https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#telepot.Bot.sendMessage.

The 2nd line makes little sense, it does not pass in the parameters that
https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#telepot.Bot.editMessageLiveLocation
explains you need.
I see no `msg_identifier`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304087/why-does-venue-telepot-isnt-correct